# Twilio Voice Alphabetic Characters

Tags: c#, twilio

Is it possible through Twilio Voice services to "gather" alphabetic letters from the phone keypad.  I know I can easily gather digits, but can I gather alphabetic letters.  So I could gather a user entry such as "ABC123"?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid Twilio will only deliver you the numbers that a user pressed. You could, however, try to work out words by turning the numbers into digits and matching against a dictionary. A bit like the [dCode tool here](http://www.dcode.fr/t9-cipher). There's a [blog post on doing this in C# here](http://blogs.u2u.be/diederik/post/2010/10/26/T9-encoding-decoding-and-prediction-in-C.aspx).

https://www.twilio.com/docs/csharp/install

Comment: That will work.  I didn't think of doing that; converting numbers to letters.  That makes sense and I can work with that.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: No problem, hope it goes well!